# Validation is not occur with flask

Tags: python, flask

> I need to check if the user has correctly enter an otp , if the user
> attempt is greater than 3 , I need to block his account.But on my cmd
> the index is decreasing , it only redirect to the page without making
> any validation.

```py
@user.route('/checkotp', methods=["GET"])
def render_checkotp_form():
    
    return render_template('sendemailform.html')

@user.route('/checkotp', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def user_ath():
    if 'index' not in session:
        session['index'] = 3

    if 'id' in session and 'otp' in session:
        ckopt = request.form.get('txtotp')
        index = session['index']

        if request.method == "POST":
            if ckopt != session['otp']:
                index -= 1
                session['index'] = index
                print('Invalid Otp')
                print(f'Attempt left {index}')
                if index == 0:
                    print('Account Block')
                    return redirect(url_for('user.account_blocked'))
                else:
                    return redirect(url_for('user.opt_formcheck'))
            else:
                print('OTP match')
                
                session['index'] = 3
                session.pop('otp', None)
                return redirect(url_for('user.change_pw'))
        else:
            return render_template('sendemailform.html')
    else:
        return render_template('home.html')
```

Comment: Please create abn MVP and share it so that we can quickly test it and provide an answer. Also it is not clear that it is redirecting to which URL.